# add header by list category in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building a sample transaction app with the ability to categorize the list item based on its category. e.g. user can add a new list item with category `sport` and i would like to have a sport as header in the recyclerview and later on if item with category `movie` added, then the new item will be under movie.

I understand that i have to provide the `itemViewType` in my adapter class. and then i will have a `List<txn>` that mixed with different view types.

my current approach in following block is using `Map<String, List<Item>>` to keep track of each new item for particular category. But I was told one of my colleague that there is more efficient way to handle this.

But what kind of data structures I should use so that I can support

1. user can add any new category.
2. when user use the existing category,
   then it should be add into the particular section in the recycler
   view only?

   ```
   public class txnAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

   public static final int TRANSCATION_TYPE = 1;
   public static final int HEAD_TYPE = 2;
   private List<Txn> txns;
   private List<Object> items;
   private Map<String, List<Txn>> map;

   public txnAdapter() {
       map = new HashMap<>();
       txns = new ArrayList<>();
       items = new ArrayList<>();
   }

   public void setTxns(List<Txn> txns) {
       //make a copy
       this.txns.addAll(txns);
       addToMap(txns);
       resetList(this.txns);
   }

   public void addTxn(Txn txn) {
       //filter by type and insert.
       //find the index of category in list and
       List<Txn> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add(txn);
       addToMap(list);
       resetList(this.txns);
   }

   void addToMap(List<Txn> txns){
       for(Txn t: txns){
           if(!map.containsKey(t.getCategory())){
               map.put(t.getCategory(), new ArrayList<Txn>());
           }
           List<Txn> list = map.get(t.getCategory());
           list.add(t);
           map.put(t.getCategory(), list);
       }
   }

   void resetList(List<Txn> txns) {
       items.clear();

       for(Map.Entry<String, List<Txn>> e: map.entrySet()){
           if(!items.contains(e.getKey())){
               items.add(e.getKey());
           }
           items.addAll(e.getValue());
       }
       notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       //inflat the layout

       View itemView = null;

       if (viewType == HEAD_TYPE) {
           itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, parent, false);
           return new headerViewHolder(itemView);
       } else if (viewType == TRANSCATION_TYPE) {
           itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
           return new transcationViewHolder(itemView);
       }

       return new transcationViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Object cur = this.items.get(position);

       if (holder instanceof headerViewHolder) {
           ((headerViewHolder) holder).gategoryTV.setText((String) cur);
       } else if (holder instanceof transcationViewHolder) {

           ((transcationViewHolder) holder).titleTV.setText(((Txn) cur).getTitle());
           ((transcationViewHolder) holder).dateTV.setText(((Txn) cur).getDate());
           ((transcationViewHolder) holder).amountTV.setText(((Txn) cur).getAmount() + "");
       }

   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return items == null ? 0 : items.size();
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {

       if (items.get(position) instanceof String) {
           //this is header
           return HEAD_TYPE;
       } else if (items.get(position) instanceof Txn) {
           return TRANSCATION_TYPE;
       }
       return -1;
   }


   private class transcationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       private TextView titleTV;
       private TextView dateTV;
       private TextView amountTV;

       public transcationViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);

           this.titleTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
           this.dateTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
           this.amountTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
       }
   }

   private class headerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       private TextView gategoryTV;

       public headerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           this.gategoryTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
       }
   }
   ```

[image: expected result group by any new header]

Comment: Can you provide image for your expected result?

Comment: just added. if i click the fab, user can add any new category they want and i will need to group by the category for subsequent new items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library I think it should full fill your requirements,

https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

you have to do some customisation there it surely work.